# remove empty double quote elements inside an array while leaving other elements

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to remove double quotes inside an array the array goes like this.

```
let array: string[] = ["apple"," ","orange"," ","grape","art"," "," "]
```

Comment: and then what? Javascript doesn't have bare words. Strings need to have quotes around them, otherwise your code won't work

Comment: just remove double quotes that are empty.

Comment: please specify that in the question accordingly. You can use the filter function for that https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 1):

A bad question to answer! But just for your knowledge. This will even handle `undefined`.

```js
let array = ["apple", " ", "orange", " ", "grape", "art", " ", " "];
let filtered = ["apple", " ", "orange", " ", "grape", "art", " ", " ", undefined].filter((x ="") => x.trim())
console.log(filtered)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const array = ["apple"," ","orange"," ","grape","art"," "," "];
array.filter(element => element.trim());
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score -4):

```
         let array: string[] = ["apple"," ","orange"," ","grape","art"," "," "]



             let result = array.filter(function(item,pos,self){
                return item.length > 1;
                })

          console.log(result)
```